# Rotate upper triangle of a ggplot tile heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, heatmap

I've plotted a heat-map like this:

```
ggplot(test, aes(start1, start2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = logFC), colour = "gray", size=0.05) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#0000FF","white","#FF0000"), na.value="#DAD7D3")
```

This plots the upper triangle of a heatmap. What i'd like to plot is the very same triangle, but having the hypotenuse as the `x-axis`.

[image]

How would I do that?

---

**Edit:** Added reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df1 <- mtcars[, c("gear","carb", "mpg")]

# normal tile plot
gg1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(gear, carb, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_tile() +
  xlim(c(1, 10)) +
  ylim(c(1, 10)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Expected output (rotated manually):

[image]

Related post using base plot `image()`:
[Visualising and rotating a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577092/visualising-and-rotating-a-matrix)

Possible solution example code is in [LDheatmap package](https://github.com/cran/LDheatmap/blob/master/R/LDheatmap.R) using `grid`.

Comment: @Gregor I think they/I want 45 degrees.

Comment: You'll have top lay around this, but @baptiste's answer to [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312713/rotate-a-ggplot2-plot-object) will get you close if you can resolve the clipping issues.

Comment: @BrodieG indeed close enough, but clipping issues.

Comment: @BrodieG Aha, add margins then rotate! Thank you. Do you want to add as an answer?

Comment: @zx8754 Feel free to add it yourself, you figured out the difficult part.  I almost duped it but for the clipping problem, which you resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312791) gets the output clipped at the bottom, so workaround would be to add extra plot margins then use `grid::viewport()` to rotate:

```
library(ggplot2) #ggplot2_2.2.1
library(grid)

gg1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(gear, carb, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_tile() +
  xlim(c(1, 10)) +
  ylim(c(1, 10)) +
  theme_void() +
  # add extra margins
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm")) 

# then rotate
print(gg1, vp = viewport(angle = 45))
```

[image]